# Prove that it is not necessarily the case that $|Aut(G_{1} \times G_{2})| \leq |Aut(G_{1})|\times |Aut(G_{2})|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, direct-product

I am faced with the following problem:

(a) Prove that for any groups $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$, $|Aut(G_{1}\times G_{2})| \geq |Aut(G_{1})| \cdot |Aut(G_{2})|$.

(b) Is it true that for any $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ we have the equality $|Aut(G_{1} \times G_{2})| = |Aut(G_{1})| \cdot |Aut(G_{2})|$?

**I have a solution for (a)**:

> Suppose $\alpha \in Aut(G_{1})$, $\beta \in Aut(G_{2})$. By definition, $\alpha$ is a bijective homomorphism from $G_{1}$ into $G_{1}$ and $\beta$ is a bijective homomorphism from $G_{2}$ into $G_{2}$.  Now, consider the product $\alpha \times \beta$ and an element $(x,y) \in G_{1} \times G_{2}$.  Then, $(\alpha \times \beta)(x,y) = (\alpha(x), \beta(y))$.
>
> First, we show that $(\alpha \times \beta)$ is a homomorphism:
>
> Consider $(x_{G_{1}}, x_{G_{2}})$, $(y_{G_{1}}, y_{G_{2}}) \in G_{1} \times G_{2}$. Then $(\alpha \times \beta)\left[(x_{G_{1}},x_{G_{2}})\times (y_{G_{1}}, y_{G_{2}}) \right] = (\alpha \times \beta)(x_{G_{1}}y_{G_{1}}, x_{G_{2}}y_{G_{2}})= (\alpha(x_{G_{1}}y_{G_{1}}), \beta(x_{G_{2}},y_{G_{2}})) = \left(\alpha(x_{G_{1}})\alpha(y_{G_{1}}), \beta(x_{G_{1}})\beta(y_{G_{1}})\right)\,\text{(Since }\,\alpha\, \text{and}\, \beta\, \text{are each homomorphisms)} = (\alpha(x_{G_{1}}),\beta(x_{G_{2}})) \times (\alpha(y_{G_{1}}),\beta(y_{G_{2}})) = (\alpha \times \beta)(x_{G_{1}},x_{G_{2}}) \times (\alpha \times \beta)(y_{G_{1}},y_{G_{2}})$. So, $(\alpha \times \beta)$ is a homomorphism.
>
> Next, we must show that $(\alpha \times \beta) $ is injective:
>
> Suppose that $\forall (x,y) \in G_{1} \times G_{2}$, $(\alpha_{1} \times \beta_{1})(x,y) = (\alpha_{2} \times \beta_{2})(x,y)$ $\implies$ $(\alpha_{1}(x), \beta_{1}(y)) = (\alpha_{2}(x), \beta_{2}(y)) $.
>
> Now, we must show that $\alpha_{1} = \alpha_{2}$.
>
> Suppose that it is not, then $\exists$ some $x^{\prime} \in G_{1}$ such that $\alpha_{1}(x^{\prime}) \neq \alpha_{2}(x^{\prime})$.
>
> Then, consider $(\alpha_{1} \times \beta_{1})(x^{\prime}, e_{G_{2}}) = (\alpha_{2} \times \beta_{2})(x^{\prime}, e_{G_{2}})$ $\implies $ $(\alpha_{1}(x^{\prime}), \beta_{1}(e_{G_{2}})) = (\alpha_{2}(x^{\prime}),\beta_{2}(e_{G_{2}}))$.
>
> But, since $\beta_{1}$ and $\beta_{2}$ are injective, $\beta_{1}(e_{G_{2}}) = e_{G_{2}}$ and $\beta_{2}(e_{G_{2}}) = e_{G_{2}}$.
>
> So, we have that $(\alpha_{1} \times \beta_{1})(x^{\prime}, e_{G_{2}}) = (\alpha_{2} \times  \beta_{2}) (x^{\prime}, e_{G_{2}}) \, \implies \, (\alpha_{1}(x^{\prime}), e_{G_{2}}) = (\alpha_{2}(x^{\prime}), e_{G_{2}}) 
> \, \implies \, \alpha_{1}(x^{\prime}) = \alpha_{2}(x^{\prime})$ when we assumed it was not (contradiction).
>
> Then, I did something very similar for $\beta$ to show that $\forall y^{\prime} \in G_{2}$, we must have that $\beta_{1}(y^{\prime})=\beta_{2}(y^{\prime})$.
>
> Together, these things tell us that $\alpha \times \beta$ is an injective homomorphism, and since it essentially maps the images of $x \in G_{1}$ under $\alpha$ and the images of $y \in G_{2}$ under $\beta$ to the images in $G_{1} \times G_{2}$ under $\alpha \times \beta$, its being injective tells us that $|Aut(G_{1} \times G_{2})| \geq |Aut(G_{1})| \times |Aut(G_{2})|$.

**Now, my question is how to prove part (b)**.

I'm assuming that in order to show that $|Aut(G_{1} \times Aut(G_{2})| = |Aut(G_{1})| \cdot |Aut(G_{2})|$, we must, in addition to showing that $|Aut(G_{1} \times G_{2})| \geq |Aut(G_{1})| \times |Aut(G_{2})|$, we must show the reverse inequality: $|Aut(G_{1} \times G_{2})| \leq |Aut(G_{1})| \times |Aut(G_{2})|$.

Since we used injectivity to prove the $\geq$ direction, I'm assuming we would use surjectivity to prove the $\leq$ direction?

However, I am inclined to believe that the answer is false. I have heard that for finite groups $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$, it doesn't work unless $\gcd(|G_{1}|, |G_{2}|) = 1$, so I'd want to state that (b) is not true except for when $|G_{1}|$ and $|G_{2}|$ are finite and $\gcd(|G_{1}|, |G_{2}|) = 1$. But, **1) I'm not sure how to prove this, and 2) would I then effectively be proving that this is the ONLY case where we have the $\leq$ direction (I sometimes tend to overthink the logic; be patient with me, I'm learning!)?**

If I could get some written out help for these things, I would be most appreciative!

Comment: The question does not ask you to prove (b). It asks you whether (b) is true. To prove it's false, you just need one counterexample.

Comment: Good work so far! You could be asking one of two things: (1) how do you solve part (b) of the original question; or (2) how can you prove the stronger statement in your 2nd-to-last paragraph. As for (1), you can simply find a single counterexample. What are the smallest groups you can think of whose cardinalities are not relatively prime?

Comment: @GregMartin which second-to-last paragraph? I'm not sure what you're talking about there.

Comment: 2nd-to-last of the paragraphs you wrote. "However, I am inclined ... learning!)?"

Comment: @GregMartin I think I just need to solve part (b). These groups you're talking about, you mean like $Z_{m}$ and $Z_{n}$ where $n$ and $m$ are not relatively prime?

Comment: @GregMartin do those groups sound good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the example where $G_1=G_2=Z/2Z$ and compute the automorphism groups.

Comment: and that would be sufficient?

Comment: And what do you mean $G_{1} = G_{1}$? Do you mean let $G_{1} = G_{2} = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Of course I do.

Comment: And one more question for you @MarianoSuarez-Alvarez is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ the same thing as $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$?

Comment: because then we'd have  on the one hand $|Aut(\mathbb{Z_{2}} \times \mathbb{Z_{2}})|$, which is the number of automorphisms on the Klein-4 group, and on the other hand, the square of the number of automorphisms just on $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$

Comment: Yes, and? Have you computed those automorphism groups as I suggested?

Comment: I did. They each have only one automorphism in them. I'm at the very end, and I'm trying to find $|Aut(\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}|$, but it's a very roundabout thing. First, I needed to show it was isomorphic to $K_{4}$, then I needed to show that for two groups $G \simeq H$ that $Aut(G) \simeq Aut(H)$, and now it looks like I need to show that $Aut(K_{4}) \simeq S_{3}$. What a long, strange trip it's been...